# Why is this PendingIntent null after canceling?

Tags: android

I using multiple alarm on App.
Every times open app i set 4 alarm , but if when set alarm then i has remove all alarm and set again.
This is my code when set Alarm:

```
public static void setAlarm(Context context, int hour, int minute, boolean addDay, int i) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (addDay) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    int idRequest = Integer.parseInt(hour+""+minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    intent.putExtra(TYPE_ALARM, i);
    intent.putExtra(HOUR, hour);
    intent.putExtra(MINUTE, minute);
    intent.putExtra(REQUEST_CODE, (int) calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            idRequest, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    Log.d("Set Alarm", hour + ": " + minute +" "+ calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" +
            (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)+" idPedding: "+idRequest);

}
```

Android remove all Alarm:

```
public static void cancleAlarm(Context context, int hour, int minute, int i) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    intent.putExtra(TYPE_ALARM, i);
    intent.putExtra(HOUR, hour);
    intent.putExtra(MINUTE, minute);
    intent.putExtra(REQUEST_CODE, calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    int idRequest = Integer.parseInt(hour+""+minute);
    PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, idRequest,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    // Cancel alarms
    try {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
        Log.d(TAG, "Cancle-PeddingCodeGet: " + i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
    }
    Log.d("cancle Alarm", hour + ":" + minute +" "+ calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" +
            (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)+" idPedding: "+idRequest);
}
```

But, when i remove all alarm, i debug see PendingIntent alway null.Although
, before i was set list alarm.
I cant check it cancled.
So, How remove the alarm list?

Comment: int idRequest = Integer.parseInt(hour+""+minute);                  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,    idRequest, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);                                    PendingIntent request id must be unique .In your way it may override alarm if hour+minute are same.

Comment: I want set multiple alarm, ex: 10:00 , 12:00, 13:00...if same requestID i think penddingIntent will replace..and only last alarm active.